# how to used to spring-lettucemod create index on json（java）

Tags: redis, lettuce, redisjson

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kGrK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paQ2e.png)

I create a redissearch index with spring-lettucemod,but the Index is Hash type ,not the JSON type,I can't find the Options to change the Hash on CreateOptions or RedisModulesCommands,Please god give advice or comments

Answer (score 0):

```
 TagField<String> tagField = Field.tag(indexJSONPath).as(tagName).build();
Field<String>[] fields = new Field[]{tagField};

CreateOptions<String, String> options = CreateOptions.<String, String>builder()
                                                     .prefix(prefix)
                                                     .on(CreateOptions.DataType.JSON)
                                                     .build();

return connection.reactive()
                 .ftCreate(index, options, fields);
```

Super simplistic example.